# Использование Thread.sleep() в java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Если создать поток (например, `threadOne`), а потом в main'е главного потока написать `threadOne.sleep()`, то уснёт основной поток, так как `sleep` - статической метод и относится лишь к вызывающему его потоку. Возникает вопрос: для чего же таки существует возможность писать  `threadOne.sleep()`, если смысла в этом нет? А если смысл есть (по-идее, должен быть), то как это использовать?

Comment: К статик полям можно обращаться через экземпляр класса, потоки тут ни причем, это фича языка.

Comment: Вы видите здесь плохое взаимодействие фич языка. С одной стороны, статический метод можно вызывать из любого экземпляра. С другой стороны, для `Thread.sleep()` статический метод относится к _конкретному_ экземпляру. Таким образом, получается не код, работающий не так, как это подсказывает интуиция. В C# для борьбы с этим, например, запрещён вызов статических методов через экземпляр класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) четко сказано, что вызов этого метода заставляет "заснуть" текущий поток. Очевидный ответ на ваш вопрос: метод нужен, чтобы заставить заснуть текущий поток.

Comment: @a_gura, это я уяснил. Мне интересно, почему sleep() и threadOne.sleep(), и threadTwo.sleep(), и threadN.sleep() действуют одинаково. Может быть, это можно как-то использовать? Или, как сказал gcoder, это фича языка?

Comment: @111xbot111, Это никак нельзя использовать. С точки зрения компилятора, это прямой вызов процедуры вне зависимости о того, как был вызван метод, через объект или класс.