# Проблема с очередностью выполнения потоков в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency

Есть задание

> Разработать многопоточное приложение. Использовать возможности,
>   предоставляемые пакетом java.util.concurrent. **Не использовать слово
>   synchronized и блокирующие очереди.** Все сущности, желающие получить доступ к ресурсу, должны
>   быть потоками. Использовать возможности ООП. Не использовать
>   графический интерфейс. Приложение должно быть кон- сольным

Конкретный вариант задания:

> Свободная касса. В ресторане быстрого обслуживания есть несколько
>   касс. Посетители стоят в очереди в конкретную кассу, но могут перейти
>   в другую очередь при уменьшении или исчезновении там очереди.

Код ресторана:

```
public class Restaurant {
    private static Restaurant instance = null;
    private static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<CashDesk> cashDesks;

    private Restaurant(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        cashDesks = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static Restaurant getInstance(String name) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new Restaurant(name);
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void addCashDesk(CashDesk cashDesk) {
        cashDesks.add(cashDesk);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<CashDesk> getCashDesks() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(cashDesks);
    }
}
```

Код клиента:

```
public class Client extends Thread {
    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Client.class);
    private Restaurant restaurant;
    private CashDesk cashDesk;
    private String name;
    private int itemsInOrder;

    public Client(Restaurant restaurant, int itemsInOrder, String name) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
        this.itemsInOrder = itemsInOrder;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getItemsInOrder() {
        return itemsInOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Client " + name + " comes to restaurant " + restaurant.getName());
        this.cashDesk = chooseCashDesk();
        System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() + " choosed the cashDesk#"+ cashDesk.getNumber());
        cashDesk.addClient(this);
        while (true) {
            if (cashDesk.getLock().tryLock()) {
                try {
                    cashDesk.serveClient(this);
                } catch (ResourceException e) {
                    LOG.error("ResourceException!!! ", e);
                } finally {
                    cashDesk.getLock().unlock();
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (canChooseAnotherCashDesk()) {
                    cashDesk.removeClient(this);
                }
            }
        }
        cashDesk.removeClient(this);
        System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() + " leaves restaurant");
    }

    private CashDesk chooseCashDesk(){
        CashDesk result = restaurant.getCashDesks().get(0);
        for (CashDesk cashDesk : restaurant.getCashDesks()) {
            if(cashDesk.getClients().size() < result.getClients().size()) {
                result = cashDesk;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean canChooseAnotherCashDesk() {
        CashDesk result = chooseCashDesk();
        if(result.getClients().size() + 1 < cashDesk.getClients().size()) {
            cashDesk = result;
            cashDesk.addClient(this);
            System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() + " moved to cashDesk#" + cashDesk.getNumber());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Код кассы:

```
public class CashDesk {

    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private LinkedList<Client> clients;
    private int number;
    private int timeOfService;

    public CashDesk(int number, int timeOfService) {
        clients = new LinkedList<>();
        this.number = number;
        this.timeOfService = timeOfService;

    }

    public void serveClient(Client client) throws ResourceException {
        System.out.println("Client "+client.getClientName() + " is serving on cashDesk#"+getNumber());
        try {
            client.sleep(timeOfService * client.getItemsInOrder());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new ResourceException("InterruptedException!!!", e);
        }
        System.out.println("Client "+client.getClientName() + " is served");
    }

    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(clients);
    }

    public void addClient(Client client) {
        clients.add(client);
    }

    public void removeClient(Client client) {
        clients.remove(client);
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public ReentrantLock getLock() {
        return lock;
    }
}
```

Запуск:

```
public class RestaurantRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Restaurant restaurant = Restaurant.getInstance("Mcdonalds");
        CashDesk cashDesk1 = new CashDesk(1, 140);
        CashDesk cashDesk2 = new CashDesk(2, 250);

        restaurant.addCashDesk(cashDesk1);
        restaurant.addCashDesk(cashDesk2);


        new Client(restaurant, 100, "client50").start();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {

            int randNumbOfItems = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
            Client client =  new Client(restaurant, randNumbOfItems, "client"+i);
            client.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот что я получаю после запуска:

```
Client client1 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client1 choosed the cashDesk#1
Client client1 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client3 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client3 choosed the cashDesk#2
Client client3 is serving on cashDesk#2
Client client5 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client5 choosed the cashDesk#1
Client client6 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client6 choosed the cashDesk#2
Client client4 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client4 choosed the cashDesk#1
Client client50 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client50 choosed the cashDesk#2
Client client7 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client7 choosed the cashDesk#1
Client client2 comes to restaurant Mcdonalds
Client client2 choosed the cashDesk#2
Client client1 is served
Client client5 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client1 leaves restaurant
Client client3 is served
Client client3 leaves restaurant
Client client50 is serving on cashDesk#2
Client client5 is served
Client client5 leaves restaurant
Client client7 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client7 is served
Client client7 leaves restaurant
Client client6 moved to cashDesk#1
Client client6 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client2 moved to cashDesk#1
Client client6 is served
Client client6 leaves restaurant
Client client2 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client2 is served
Client client2 leaves restaurant
Client client4 is serving on cashDesk#1
Client client4 is served
Client client4 leaves restaurant
Client client50 is served
Client client50 leaves restaurant
```

Как видно, очередь обслуживания нарушается

Когда client3 обслужен client6 должен начать обслуживаться, так как пришел после client3 во вторую кассу, но вместо него это делает client50, хотя пришел после client6. Аналогично когда client5 обслужен client4 должен начать обслуживаться, но это делает client7. Также когда client7 обслужен не понимаю почему но client6 переходит к cashDesk#1 и начинает обслуживаться, несмотря на то что уже давно должен обслуживаться client4

Я в многопоточности новичок, поэтому нужен совет, как добиться корректной работы приложения, спасибо

Comment: Я довольно бегло просмотрел код, но, насколько понимаю, метод Client.run и не предусматривает никакого порядка - кто первый схватил лок, того и касса. Скорее всего, вам нужна очередь.

Comment: Похоже это задание для EPAM, да ? И если ты предъявишь это решение, то получишь работу. Тем более "новичок". Может стоит подучить саму Яву первым делом? А то на собеседовании спросят. И к тому же в этой гигантской простыне код разобраться невозможно. Сузь круг для поиска проблемы.

Comment: создание логгера и вывод через System.out.println - это пять.

Comment: @arg вывод в консоль чтобы самому проще разобраться было) да, задание для епам, и нет, если я предъявлю решение то не получу работу) это задание с тренинга по java, изучением которой и занимаюсь, и вот в при выполнении "зашел в тупик", почему собственно и спрашиваю совета

Comment: @Etki тоесть касса должна содержать очередь из клиентов и последовательно их обслуживать?

Comment: Ну а как еще? Это может быть ручная реализация очереди, но именно  в порядке очереди же они обслуживаются в моделируемой ситуации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы делаете многие вещи неправильно.

Для начала, почему вы видите такой порядок обслуживания. Дел в том, что у вас `serveClient` является публичной функцией, за которую борются клиенты. Это неправильно. Это скорее напоминает не очередь, а толпу вокруг окошка кассы, где каждый пытается распихнуть остальных и пролезть первым. Не делайте так, пусть очередью занимается `CashDesk`, тогда и не нужно будет выставлять `lock` наружу.

Что у нас получается с `CashDesk`?

```
// у CashDesk есть своя логика работы, пусть это тоже будет поток
public class CashDesk : Thread {

    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private LinkedList<Client> clients;
    private int number;
    private int timeOfService;
    private bool isShutdownRequested;

    public CashDesk(int number, int timeOfService) {
        clients = new LinkedList<>();
        this.number = number;
        this.timeOfService = timeOfService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // по существу, мы здесь должны заимплементировать
        // producer/consumer (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105)
        // разберитесь и переделайте правильно
        while (true) {
            Client client = null;
            try {
                lock.lock();
                if (isShutdownRequested)
                    break;
                if (clients.size() > 0)
                    client = clients.removeFirst();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
            if (client == null) {
                // поллинг вместо честной имплементации consumer
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                continue;
            }
            serveClient(client);
        }
    }

    // метод serveClient теперь приватный
    private void serveClient(Client client) throws ResourceException {
        System.out.println("Client " + client.getClientName() +
           " is serving on cashDesk#" + getNumber());
        //try {
            // так делать нельзя, вы вызываете статический метод
            // Thread.sleep, и засыпает **текущий** поток
            // см. например http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/363383/10105
            // client.sleep(timeOfService * client.getItemsInOrder());
            // сответственно и весь try/catch не нужен
        //} catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //    throw new ResourceException("InterruptedException!!!", e);
        //}
        // что нужно:
        // 1. сообщить клиенту, что его обслуживают, чтобы он
        //    не пытался сбежать из очереди
        if (!client.StartServe(this))
            // пока мы начинали, клиент уже мог сбежать из очереди
            // если так, ничего больше не делаем
            return;
        Thread.sleep(timeOfService * client.getItemsInOrder());
        client.FinishServe();
        System.out.println("Client " + client.getClientName() + " is served");
    }

    // это публичный метод, может быть вызван из любого потока.
    // добавьте блокировку! (мне лень)
    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(clients);
    }

    // и здесь
    public void addClient(Client client) {
        if (isShutdownRequested)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("очередь больше не принимает");
        clients.add(client);
    }

    // и здесь
    public void removeClient(Client client) {
        clients.remove(client);
    }

    // неизменяемые данные, блокировка не нужна
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    // неееееет! блокировка - внутренняя подробность нашего класса
    //public ReentrantLock getLock() {
    //    return lock;
    //}
}
```

Теперь клиент. Клиент получает меньше обязанностей.

```
public class Client extends Thread {
    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Client.class);
    private Restaurant restaurant;
    private CashDesk cashDesk;
    private String name;
    private int itemsInOrder;
    private boolean isBeingServed;
    private boolean isServed;

    public Client(Restaurant restaurant, int itemsInOrder, String name) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
        this.itemsInOrder = itemsInOrder;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getItemsInOrder() {
        return itemsInOrder;
    }

    public boolean StartServe(CashDesk cashDesk) {
        lock.lock();
        try
        {
            if (cashDesk != this.cashDesk)
                return false;
            if (isServed)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(...);
            isBeingServed = true;
            return true;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void FinishServe() {
        lock.lock();
        try
        {
            if (!isBeingServed)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(...);
            isBeingServed = false;
            isServed = true;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Client " + name + " comes to restaurant " + restaurant.getName());

        if (!tryEnterQueue(chooseCashDesk())) {
            System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() +
                " couldn't enqueue to the cashDesk#"+ cashDesk.getNumber());
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() +
            " chosen the cashDesk#"+ cashDesk.getNumber());

        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            boolean finishLoop = isBeingServed;
            lock.unlock();
            if (finishLoop)
                break;

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            // попытаемся найти очередь получше
            switchToBetterCashDeskIfPossible();
            if (cashDesk == null)
                break;
        }

        // если мы тут, нас обслуживают, ждём окончания
        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            boolean finishLoop = isServed;
            lock.unlock();
            if (finishLoop)
                break;

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() + " is eating");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() + " leaves restaurant");
    }

    private CashDesk chooseCashDesk() {
        CashDesk result = restaurant.getCashDesks().get(0);
        for (CashDesk cashDesk : restaurant.getCashDesks()) {
            if(cashDesk.getClients().size() < result.getClients().size()) {
                result = cashDesk;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean tryEnterQueue(CashDesk cashDesk) {
        // попытка стать в новую очередь может выбросить исключение
        try {
            cashDesk.addClient(this);
            this.cashDesk = cashDesk;
            return true;
        } catch (InvalidOperationException) {
            System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() +
               " cannot enqueue to cashDesk#" + cashDesk.getNumber() +
               " and doesn't know what to do");
            return false;
        }
    }

    // называть метод, который реально сменяет очередь, canSwitch
    // неправильно. метод canSwitch может лишь проверять.
    // поэтому переименуем метод
    private void switchToBetterCashDeskIfPossible() {
        lock.lock();
        bool skipSwitch = isBeingServed;
        lock.unlock();
        if (skipSwitch)
            return;            
        CashDesk result = chooseCashDesk();
        if (result == cashDesk)
            return;
        cashDesk.removeClient(this);

        if (tryEnterQueue(cashDesk)) {
            System.out.println("Client " + getClientName() + " moved to cashDesk#" + cashDesk.getNumber());
        }
    }
}
```

Что ещё нужно сделать?

Уберите циклы ожидания, и пользуйтесь семафорами или `CountDownLatch`. Ресторан вам не нужен как синглтон, лучше уберите его и конструируйте вручную. (Подумайте, что будет, если кто-то вызовет

```
Restaurant r1 = Restaurant.getInstance("Mcdonalds");
Restaurant r2 = Restaurant.getInstance("KFC");
```

— он получит два Макдональдса!) Ну и тестируйте.